# can anyone help me with this part? : ADC81S021

Tags: adc

i googled the P/N and can't even find who the manufacturer is and, what i really want, is a spec sheet.

it's in a board already, and someone just sent me an iPhone photo of the board schematic.  i can tell it's hooked up to the SPI of the DSP i am using, but i don't have any idea what the input voltage range is (Va is 3.3v so i suspect it's 0 to 3 volts or something) nor the protocol of the bits coming out (MSB/LSB first?) nor even how many bits?  or the samples per second or conversion time?

it appears to be a very cheap part, only 6 pins, and when you consider the SCLK and CS, i don't think it has any pins to spare.

but i can't find a single site for the data sheet on this thing.  and that surprizes me.  i found one site that sells it, and then a couple of sites that sell a product using this part.

where can i get a data sheet?  who even is the manufacturer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct link to the TI product page.

http://www.ti.com/product/ADC081S021

It looks to be correct, you may have just been missing the 0 in the part number.

6 pin, 8 bit, SPI ADC.

[image: adc1]

[image: adc2]

Comment: yup, that's the reason.  but i had no idea of that leading 0.  it was not on the schematic and there were a few other hits, but none that pointed to the manufacturer.